# How can I execute statements with in order using JDBC and Statement.executeQuery()?

Tags: java, jdbc

I use JDBC to insert some values into a table.
I iterate over the statemets and I wnt to execute them in the order they come:

```
 for (String statement : statements) {
      System.out.println(statement);
      stmt.executeQuery(statement);
 }
```

In console  the statements are printed:

```
insert into results (cod_prod,cod_prod1,scor_prod1,cod_prod2,scor_prod2,cod_prod3,scor_prod3,cod_prod4,scor_prod4) values(9100100123256,8692857013184,9.93973798303341,8710908117671,9.653580483609403,6423038000042,9.181317277303606,90005848,9.181317277303606)
insert into results (cod_prod) values(90494741)
...
```

And I expect they are executed in this order, but when I query the database I get the rows in different order:

[image: img]

Why it happend in this way? The stmt.executeQuery(statement) open a process and it executes lower of faster depending on the statement (number of values inserted, etc)? And it should be synchronized?

Could you give me an example of how can I execute statementsin the order the foreach give them?

Comment: A SELECT query without an ORDER BY clause will return rows in an arbitrary order (ie, the ordering is undefined). That is because relational tables have no specific ordering of the rows in them.

Comment: please share your table definition, is there any column defined as auto increased? When I compare your log and your select, I didn't see the records in the table but in your console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating and printing a Java `ArrayList` or some other structure and that Java data structure has **insertion - order** maintained.

Your table is a RDBMS table and it doesn't have any such automatic ordering. In your `SELECT`, you can use SQL . `ORDER BY` clause on a column to order result set rows in any order that you want.